# ListView background attribute causes all items to be highlighted when one is selected

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

[image: Screenshot while pressing]

In my Android app, when the user presses an item in my List, the item correctly gets highlighted blue, but all of  the other items in the list also get highlighted grey. When the user lifts their finger, the highlights go away. This causes a "flicker" effect on the whole list that is undesirable.

If I remove just the background attribute from the ListView, the flicker effect goes away. I'm looking for another fix so I can keep the background attribute.

I am using Android 17.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="8dip"
    android:paddingTop="0dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:textColor="@color/my_sky"
        android:background="@drawable/my_btn_white"
        android:id="@+id/my_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        style="@style/MY.Flow.Button"
        android:id="@+id/my_add_choices"
        android:text="@string/my_favorites_add_choices"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried both android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" and
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000", as those were suggested in other threads, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. My @drawable/my_btn_white had the following line:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/my_btn_white_active"/>
```

When I remove this line, the grey highlight, and thus the flicker, goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Try add to your `ListView`

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: That has no effect. :(

Comment: Added. That was taken with cacheColorHint set to #00000000.